# How to show redirects in curl or other utility?

Tags: python, unix, curl

When I type in the url http://www.hulu.com/bill-hicks-relentless, it takes me to the page http://www.hulu.com/watch/768345.

How would I be able to do the following, without actually loading the page or getting any content of it, in pseudocode:

```
$ curl -X http://www.hulu.com/bill-hicks-relentless
http://www.hulu.com/watch/768345
```

Is there a python utility to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `requests` to do this quite easily:

```
>>> requests.head('http://www.hulu.com/bill-hicks-relentless').headers.get('location')
```

'http://www.hulu.com/watch/768345'